# bundle install fails due to ff1 gem even if gem install ffi is successful

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ffi, rbenv

**Steps I did**

1. Installed rbenv - Installation successful
   `rbenv install 3.1.2`
2. Installed bundler gem - Successfull
   `gem install bundler`
3. **ran the bundle install command** - ***Failed***
   `bundle install`

**Output:**

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using aws-sigv4 1.0.0
Using jmespath 1.3.1
Using aws-sdk-core 2.7.15
Using aws-sdk-resources 2.7.15
Using aws-sdk 2.7.15
Using bundler 1.17.2
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using colored 1.2
Using deep_merge 1.0.1
Using configure-s3-website 2.0.0
Using dotenv 1.0.2
Fetching ffi 1.15.4
Installing ffi 1.15.4 with native extensions
Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /Users/sucm/Development/Projects/dots-ruby3/dots.co/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/CHANGELOG.md
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.15.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll was resolved to 3.6.3, which depends on
    jekyll-sass-converter was resolved to 1.5.2, which depends on
      sass was resolved to 3.7.4, which depends on
        sass-listen was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
          rb-inotify was resolved to 0.10.1, which depends on
            ffi
```

**Other commands** that I ran. Still fail to pass the `bundle install` step

1. `gem install ffi -v '1.15.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` // Successful
2. `gem install ffi -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"` // Successful
3. `bundle update ffi` // Fails with the above similar bundle install error

Output for the command `bundle env`

```
sucm@11575A-SUCM dots.co % bundle env
/Users/sucm/.zshrc:8: no such file or directory: /Users/sucm/.rbenv/bin/rbenv
zsh:1: command not found: chruby

Saving session...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
## Environment
```

Bundler       1.17.2
Platforms   ruby, universal-darwin-21
Ruby          2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
Full Path   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
Config Dir  /Library/Ruby/Site
RubyGems      3.0.3.1
Gem Home    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
Gem Path    /Users/sucm/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
User Path   /Users/sucm/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
Bin Dir     /usr/local/bin
Tools
Git         2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)
RVM         not installed
rbenv       rbenv 1.2.0
chruby      Restored session: Thu Nov 24 16:28:32 IST 2022

```
## Bundler Build Metadata
```

Built At          2018-12-19
Git SHA           3fc4de72b
Released Version  false

```
## Bundler settings
```

build.ffi
Set for your local app (/Users/sucm/Development/Projects/dots-ruby3/dots.co/.bundle/config): "--with-cflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
Set for the current user (/Users/sucm/.bundle/config): "--with-cflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
path
Set for your local app (/Users/sucm/Development/Projects/dots-ruby3/dots.co/.bundle/config): "vendor/bundle"

````
## Gemfile

### Gemfile

```ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'jekyll'
gem 's3_website'
````

#### Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    aws-sdk (2.7.15)
      aws-sdk-resources (= 2.7.15)
    aws-sdk-core (2.7.15)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.0)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-resources (2.7.15)
      aws-sdk-core (= 2.7.15)
    aws-sigv4 (1.0.0)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    colored (1.2)
    configure-s3-website (2.0.0)
      aws-sdk (~> 2)
      deep_merge (~> 1.0.0)
    deep_merge (1.0.1)
    dotenv (1.0.2)
    ffi (1.15.4)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    jekyll (3.6.3)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-sass-converter (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 1.1)
      kramdown (~> 1.14)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (~> 0.3.3)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (>= 1.7, < 3)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
    jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.2)
      sass (~> 3.4)
    jekyll-watch (1.5.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    jmespath (1.3.1)
    kramdown (1.17.0)
    liquid (4.0.3)
    listen (3.7.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mercenary (0.3.6)
    pathutil (0.16.2)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rouge (2.2.1)
    s3_website (3.0.0)
      colored (= 1.2)
      configure-s3-website (= 2.0.0)
      dotenv (~> 1.0)
      thor (~> 0.18)
    safe_yaml (1.0.5)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    thor (0.19.4)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  jekyll
  s3_website

BUNDLED WITH
   1.14.5
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and finally found a fix by forcing usage of the builtin libffi version:

```
gem install ffi -- --disable-system-libffi
bundle config build.ffi --disable-system-libffi
```

Reference: [ffi/ffi: Ruby FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi):

> The ffi gem comes with a builtin libffi version, which is used, when the system libffi library is not available or too old. Use of the system libffi can be... prevented by `--disable-system-libffi`.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily, i already had this from before:

```
bundle config build.ffi --disable-system-libffi
```

Looking at FFI's docs, they recommend `gem install ffi -- --enable-system-libffi`, and that worked for me ‍♂️